# My Vuex getter is not getting automatically updated.. how I can debug it?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vuex with a getter that filters a lot of data and then some components present it to the user grouped by status. The user can increment the visible count of elements per status by 5. How many items are visible currently is on the Vuex store and a getter uses this to create a "View object".

When I update this visibility object the getter is no rerun so something in the dependency tracking went south. I'm not adding or deleteing properties, still I'm using `Vue.set(...)` just to be sure.

This is the mutation that increments the visible amount of items for a status:

```
  viewMore(state, status) {
    console.log('viewMore')
    const current = state.visibility.statuses[status]
    Vue.set(state.visibility.statuses, status, current + 5)
  }
```

This mutation is running well and **I can see in the developer tools how the visibility increments reactively with every commit**. Now here is the getter that depends on this data:

```
  visibleProspects(state, getters) {
    console.log('visibleProspects')
    let result = {}
    for (const status in getters.sourceData) {
      if (!result[status]) {
        result[status] = { prospects: [] }
      }
      getters.sourceData[status].forEach(function(prospect) {
        if (result[status].prospects.length < state.visibility.statuses[status])
          result[status].prospects.push(prospect)
      })
    }
    return result
  }
```

What this does is traverses a complex getter named sourceData (not shown here for brevity) and then depending on how many visible items there are it returns a new structure with that maximum in an array. `visibleProspects` is then used by my components and everything runs fine **the first time** or if a update the data that sourceData computes (e.g adding / editing / deleting a prospect).. but no matter what I do modifying `state.visibility.statuses` is not forcing `visibleProspects` to recompute.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make deep copy to make it reactive (using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```
viewMore(state, status) {
    console.log('viewMore')
    const current = state.visibility.statuses[status]
    state.visibility.statuses[status] = current + 5
    state.visibility = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.visibility))
}
```

Comment: If it's not reactive.. 1) Why the devtools are updating? 2) How I can programatically see if some property at some level is reactive or not?

Strange also I've used others deeply nested structures on state and they were reactive (meaning getters got updated after modifying them)..

Comment: If you're using Vue.set on `state.visibility` it will work. But if change `state.visibility.statuses` it will not works, because `state.visibility` still point to old reference.

Comment: I will try.. but that means that only the first children of state is reactive? that goes against everything I've seen before..

Answer (score 0):

@ittus 's answer should work. But the clone operation would be heavy if your state is big.

alternatively, you may try using `Vue.set` on the root state `state.visibility` instead. This should make the reactivity works as expected.

```
Vue.set(state.visibility, 'statuses', {
    ...state.visibility.statuses,
    [status]: current + 5
})
```